# WITH ROLLUP Requiring SUM in Select?

Tags: sql, t-sql, rollup

No one was able to help me out with my original question ([WITH ROLLUP is only producing NULLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917043/with-rollup-is-only-producing-nulls))

I have since then found PART of a solution. I trimmed down my query to the following.

```
SELECT
    wlc.WorkloadCategory
    ,wl.WorkloadMinutes
FROM
    swam.WorkloadCategories  wlc
INNER JOIN  
    swam.Workloads wl 
        ON wlc.WorkloadCategoryID = wl.WorkloadCategoryID
WHERE 
    wlc.WorkloadCategory = 'DI'
GROUP BY
    wlc.WorkloadCategory
    ,wl.WorkloadMinutes WITH ROLLUP
```

I got the following result:

```
WorkloadCategory    |   WorkloadMinutes
--------------------|------------------
DI                  |   31
DI                  |   55
DI                  |   77
DI                  |   79
DI                  |   98
DI                  |   117
DI                  |   NULL
NULL                |   NULL
```

But I was expecting (457 being the total, and NULL 457 being the grand total):

```
WorkloadCategory    |   WorkloadMinutes
--------------------|------------------
DI                  |   31
DI                  |   55
DI                  |   77
DI                  |   79
DI                  |   98
DI                  |   117
DI                  |   457
NULL                |   457
```

A colleague suggested the following change (adding SUM). It does everything correctly except row 5 (196 instead of 98, doubling the value) and the total is now 555 instead of 457.

```
SELECT
    wlc.WorkloadCategory
    ,SUM(wl.WorkloadMinutes) as WorkloadMinutes
FROM
    swam.WorkloadCategories  wlc
INNER JOIN  
    swam.Workloads wl 
        ON wlc.WorkloadCategoryID = wl.WorkloadCategoryID
WHERE 
    wlc.WorkloadCategory = 'DI'
GROUP BY
    wlc.WorkloadCategory
    ,wl.WorkloadMinutes WITH ROLLUP
```

Result:

```
WorkloadCategory    |   WorkloadMinutes
--------------------|------------------
DI                  |   31
DI                  |   55
DI                  |   77
DI                  |   79
DI                  |   196
DI                  |   117
DI                  |   555
NULL                |   555
```

Can anyone explain why SUM would partially provide what I want, but then incorrectly selects the WorkloadMinutes of ONE row? Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

Comment: Presumably the underlying resultset has two rows with 98.

Comment: Yes, it does... thank you for pointing that out. So I guess the result provided by my colleague is correct. *Here come the down-votes*

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Smith pointed out,

"Presumably the underlying resultset has two rows with 98"

... and this is why I hate inheriting projects.